# C# Building a Integer value with Binary operations from "Bits"

Tags: c#, binary, integer-arithmetic

I have a array of bytes that are actually binary values like this

```
byte[] buf = new byte[] { 0xF0, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF };
```

The binary representation is `1111 1110` (`0xFF` = `0`, `0xF0`= `1`).

The value of the integer or byte that needs to be built from this is `0xFE` (254).

I have thought about converting `buf` to a string of `1`s and `0`s and then back to an integer, but there must exist more elegant ways to accomplish this with binary operations.

The Pascal code that is known to do this perfectly is (using a string):

```pascal
  if NumberOfBytes > 0  then begin    // there was a response
     for c := Length(Str) downto 1 do begin
        Ch := Str[c];
        if (ord(ch) AND 2) = 0 then begin
           Sin := Sin + '0';
        end else begin
           Sin := Sin + '1';
        end;
        INC(Teller);
        if (Teller mod 8) = 0 then begin
            N := BinaryStrToByte(Sin);
            Edit2.Text := Edit2.Text + ByteHex(N) + ' ' ;
            Sin := '';
        end;
     end;
```

Also C code that doesn't seem to port to C# because of some differences in behavior:

```c
for(bytes = 0; bytes < len; bytes++)
 {
   newByte=0;
   for(bits=0; bits<8; bits++)
   {
     newByte >>= 1;
    if(inBuf[0]==0xff) 
    {
      newByte |= 0x80;
    }
   }
   pBuf[bytes]=newByte;
 }
```

I want to effectively loop through my original array and then put a real binary `0` or `1` into an `int` or `byte`, depending if I have the `0xF0` or `0xFF` value in at the current position.

Comment: Have a look at the [BitConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.bitconverter.toint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-class.

Comment: Uhh -- you said _"The binary representation is 1111 1110 (FF = 0, F0= 1)"_ which is QUITE confusing.  Did you mean to say something like: _"The binary representation is 1111 1111   1111 1110 (where the first and second bytes have been swapped so that the x'FF' value is position = 0, and the x'F0' is position = 1)"_ ???

Comment: Are you asking people to write the code for you? What's your question here?

Comment: Yes, it does sound confusing, but the hardware i am communicating with is giving me binary data back through the serial port, FF means 0 and F0 means 1, I have to convert it to real binary values first, and then i can use BitConverter to parse it...

Comment: @EricLippert my question is: I want to effectively loop through my original array and then put a real binary 0 or 1 into a Integer or byte , depending if i have the F0 or FF value in at the current position.

Comment: @NxtLevel Do you mean `0xFF = 1` and `0xF0 = 0`?  Otherwise your question either doesn't make sense or is very confusing.

Comment: FF is Zero and F0 is One, this is how the device i am communicating is pulling the communication line, as rx and tx is shorted on 1-wire comms, so if i get back the F0 echo, i know its trying to send me a One

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick:

```
public static void Main()
{
    byte[] buf = new byte[] { 0xF0, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF };
    byte result = 0;
    foreach(var b in buf.Reverse())
    {
        result <<= 1;
        if(b == 0xFF) result |= 1;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can replace `result = (byte)(result << 1);` with `result <<= 1;` this saves conversion and makes it more readable.

Comment: This works 100%, i still cannot understand why the C example doesn't want do its job in a straight port to C#. Very clean solution :)

Comment: @NxtLevel: The problem is probably `inBuf[0]`, here you always take the first element. Are you sure the C code for instance does not increment the pointer?

Answer (score 1):

An approach with a minimal amount of branching (and LINQ calls):

```
byte result = 0x00;
foreach(byte b in buf) {
    result >>= 0x01;
    byte bs = b;
    bs <<= 0x07;
    result |= bs;
}
```

This code makes the assumption that the least significant bit of eac byte determines whether `0` (in case of `0xf0=1111 0000`) are `1` (in case of `0xff=1111 1111`) should be added.

Demo in the Mono C# Interactive shell:

```
csharp> byte[] buf = new byte[] { 0xF0, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF };
csharp> byte result = 0x00;
csharp> foreach(byte b in buf) {
      >     result >>= 0x01;
      >     byte bs = b;
      >     bs <<= 0x07;
      >     result |= bs;
      > }
csharp> result.ToString("X");
"FE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit more generic LINQ-like solution:

Method that turns your bytes to bits(in this case expressed as Booleans)

```
public static IEnumerable<Boolean> BytesToBooleans(IEnumerable<Byte> bytes)
{
    if (bytes == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("bytes");

    return bytes
        .Select(b =>
            {
                if (b == 0xF0)
                    return false;
                if (b == 0xFF)
                    return true;
                throw new ArgumentException();
            });
}
```

Method that interprets Booleans as bits starting from the lowest:

```
public static IEnumerable<Byte> BooleansAsBitsFromLowest(this IEnumerable<Boolean> bits)
{
    if (bits == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("bits");

    Int32 bitsInByte = 0;
    Byte curByte = 0;

    foreach (var bit in bits)
    {
        var mask = (Byte)(bit ?
            0x1 : 0x0);

        mask = (Byte)(mask << bitsInByte);

        curByte |= mask;
        bitsInByte++;

        if (bitsInByte == 8)
        {
            yield return curByte;
            curByte = 0;
            bitsInByte = 0;
        }
    }

    if (bitsInByte != 0)
        yield return curByte;
}
```

And here is the usage:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[] { 0xF0, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF };

var bytesFromBits = BytesToBooleans(buf)
    .BooleansAsBitsFromLowest();

foreach (var resultingByte in bytesFromBits)
{
    Console.WriteLine(resultingByte.ToString("X2"));
}
```